# ¿Cómo configurar .htaccess para un carpeta?

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo el siguiente problema , quiero poner mi web en mi localhost, y me sale error y por que esta en una carpeta y no en la raiz.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

`http://localhost/miweb`, que tengo que colocar en mi .htaccess, para que me funcione y me salga `http://localhost/miweb/template/css/bootstrap.css` y no esto `http://localhost/template/css/bootstrap.css`

index.php

```
<?php
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", __DIR__."/tso-error.log");
session_start();
require ('engine/config.php');
#Ponemos zona horaria
date_default_timezone_set($config['timezone']);
#Cargamos la clase
include('engine/core/class.general.php');
use yurico\general;
$general = new general($config);
echo $general();
exit;
```

Comment: Tienes bien configurada tu carpeta raíz en apache? es decir lo que cargas directamente en localhost corre sin problemas?

Comment: En el servidor corre sin problemas, en mi localhost no, quiero colocarlo para hacer modificaciones y sin modificar la web, me parece que es problema del .htaccess,

Comment: Que sistema operativo estas usando? y que paqueteria tienes instalada para correr apache localmente.

Comment: Windows 7, y XAMPP 5.6.37 / PHP 5.6.37

Comment: Debes verificar que tus puertos no estén ocupados por otra aplicación, hay veces que aplicaciones como skype ocupan el puerto 80. Puedes probar cambiándole el puerto a apache por decir al 85, y luego intentas con http://localhost:85 Y la solución más facil que aplicamos todo sino tenemos nada más corriendo, desinstalar, reiniciar y volver a instalar.

Comment: Creo que no entiendes la consulta, es sobre **.htaccess** trabajo de directorios, solapamiento de rutas,  no lo que estas comentando Luis Alfredo, de todas maneras se agradece tu comentario.